# How to pass a function as a parameter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a function from a parent to child component to have the child change the parents state. Basically I have a search bar that needs to change what is displayed on the main page.

When I check the type of the function in the parent it shows up as a function but when I send and check it in the child its type is undefined. I get an error that its not a function whenever I try to call it in the child component

```
import LineChart from "./charts/LineChart";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Player from "../Components/Player";
import SearchBar from '../Components/SearchBar';

class Future extends Component {
    state = {
        players: [],
        data: [],
        playerID : ""
    };


    async componentDidMount() {
        if (Player.playerID == "") {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/random');
            const body = await response.json();
            this.setState({ players: body });
            console.log(body[0].player_id);
            this.setState({ playerID: body[0].player_id })
            this.setData(body[0].player_id)
        } else {
            this.displayPlayer(Player.playerID)
            this.setData(Player.playerID)
        }
    }

    async displayPlayer(playerID) {
        if (playerID != "") {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/get_player/' + playerID);
            const body = await response.json();
            this.setState({ players: body });
        }
    }

    onSearchChange = (value) => {
        this.setState({ playerID: value });
    }

    async setData(id) {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/goal_prediction/' + id);
        const body = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: body });
        console.log(body);
}

    render() {
        this.displayPlayer(Player.playerID)
        const { players, data, id } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar placeholder={"Search"} stateChange={this.onSearchChange} />
                {players.map(player =>
                    <div key={player.id}>
                        {player.name}'s goals
                    </div>
                )}
                <LineChart />
                Goals predicted for next season: {data.predicted_goals }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Future;
```

```
import './SearchBar.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search'; 
import Player from '../Components/Player';
import Future from '../pages/FutureStats';


function SearchBar({ placeholder }, { stateChange }) {

const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
const [wordEntered, setWordEntered] = useState("");

const handleFilter = async (event) => {
    const searchWord = event.target.value                                   // Access the value inside input
    setWordEntered(searchWord);
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/search_player/' + searchWord;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const body = await response.json();
    if (searchWord === "") {
        setFilteredData([])
    } else {
        setFilteredData(body);
    }
}

const clearInput = () => {
    setFilteredData([]);
    setWordEntered("");
    }

    const selectInput = value => () => {
        console.log(Player.playerID)
        Player.playerID
        setFilteredData([]);
        setWordEntered("");
        console.log(typeof(stateChange))
        stateChange(value);
    }

  return (
    <div className='search'>
          <div className='searchInputs'>
              <input type={"text"} value={wordEntered} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleFilter} />
            <div className='searchIcon'>
                {filteredData.length === 0 ? <SearchIcon/> : <CloseIcon id="clearButton" onClick={clearInput} />}  
            </div>
        </div>

        {filteredData.length !== 0 && (
            <div className='dataResult'>
            {filteredData.slice(0, 15).map((value) => {
                return (
                    // Stay on one page.
                    <a className="dataItem" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick={selectInput(value.player_id)}>
                        <p key={value.id}>{value.name}</p>
                 </a>
                 );
            })}
        </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: you are trying to extract it from wrong object - from context. First object is props, and you are extracting already **placeholder** from it, and second is context, and you indeed don't have anything there, so you should have something like { placeholder, stateChange }

Comment: There is only one prop to destructure `SearchBar({ placeholder, stateChange })`.

Comment: Thanks so much, you'll are life savers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stateChange` is part of your props and needs to be the first argument in your `SearchBar` function:

```
function SearchBar({ placeholder, stateChange }) {
...
```